# The result of my Jquery function is jumpy

Tags: jquery, html

I have a scroll function which fixes the div and appends, however it is extremely jumpy and flickers. here is my JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/h3thnabh/

And here is my functions;

```
    <script>

        var test = true;
        $(window).scroll(function () {

        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200 && test==true) {

        $('.main-menu-top').addClass("sticky");
        } else {
        $('.main-menu-top').removeClass("sticky");
        }
    })

    </script>    
    <script>

        var test = true;

        $( document ).scroll(function() {

        if($('.main-menu-top').hasClass('sticky') && test==true){
            test = false;
            $('.main-menu-top').append('<div id="checkout_sticky"></div>');
        }else{
            test = true;
            $('#checkout_sticky').remove();
        }
        })

    </script>
```

How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: Please describe what the desired behavior is.  How do you want it to behave?  Also, why are you using both `$(window).scroll()` event handlers and `$(document).scroll()` handlers?

Comment: @jfriend00 I would like it so when the class 'sticky' is applied, it appends a div. At the moment it is doing that but when I scroll it flickers and becomes extremely jumpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.scroll()` event handler is called potentially hundreds of times during a scroll and appears to be using some sort of flag that causes an alternating behavior.  From your description of what you want, that just doesn't appear to be the correct code.  Further, I can see no reason why you would have both document and window scroll event handlers.

I think you can just do this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200) {
        $('.main-menu-top').addClass("sticky");
        if ($("#checkout_sticky").length === 0) {
            $('.main-menu-top').append('<div id="checkout_sticky"></div>');
        }
    } else {
        $('.main-menu-top').removeClass("sticky");
        $("#checkout_sticky").remove();
    }
});
```

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/w8toujfx/

If this isn't the exact behavior you want, then please add a more detailed description (in words) of the desired behavior to your question.

Comment: what does - if ($("#checkout_sticky").length === 0) { mean/do? I haven't seen .length ===0 before it would be nice to know what it does for the future

Comment: It just checks to see if `#checkout_sticky` is already present so it won't be added if already present.  `$("#checkout_sticky")` creates a jQuery object for that selector.  Checking to see if `.length === 0` checks to see if the jQuery object is empty because that selector doesn't exist.  `.length` tells you how many matching DOM elements are in the jQuery object.  If the length is `0`, then there are no DOM elements that matched the selector.